# OpenmMP: is this code thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, openmp

I'm an OpenMP beginner and I'm using it with OpenCV. I wonder if the following code is thread safe (I omitted the reading operations to keep the code MCV):

```
cv::Mat allDescriptors;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    cv::Mat privateallDescriptors;
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for(int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++) {
        //some reading operation saved in descriptors
        privateallDescriptors.push_back(descriptors);
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    allDescriptors.push_back(privateallDescriptors);
}
```

The writing part seems safe to me, but the reading part could not be?

Comment: Looks good to me, assuming the `push_back()` function does what one expects it to do...

Comment: My main concern is: is it possible that some read only operations (e.g. read a file) are not thread safe?

Comment: Yes of course they might not be. Indeed, the usual file read is not since it changes the state of the file pointer (just by for example advancing it into the file). So it is up to you to ensure thread safety.

Comment: How could we possibly comment on the reading part that you think could not be safe, if you omit it from the code. Remember, the "C" in MCVE is for complete.

Comment: Actually if for some strange reason exists a theorem s.t. "any read-only is considered thread-safe" then you don't need the code. Just sayin'.